# RegEx to find a pattern

Tags: php, regex

Looking for regex to do the following in php:

1. Identify if the given string is in the pattern string1_string2_number e.g ph_val_34563, ph_val_296987 etc.
2. When true, extract the number part.

Comment: So write it. What's your question?

Comment: @Guilherme haven't tried anything. Regex newbie. Thought of doing it with basic php functions.

Comment: @JohnConde I want the regular expression.

Comment: @Manju well, then you should read more about how regex works and try to write some code to solve your problem. If you strive to write it and can't find why it is not working, we can help you of course. ;) Nobody here will write code for you for free.

Comment: Seems [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)... _Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions**, why they didn't work, and the expected results._

Comment: you can simply use `$pattern = '/ph_val_[1-9]*/';
preg_match_all($pattern,$ur_string, $matches);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
regex = "^[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]+_(\d+)$"
```

Assuming that the valid characters for your strings are letters, `[A-Za-z]+` says to expect a group of one or more letters.  The `_` following these character classes says that an `_` must follow.

`(\d+)` says to group, and capture, a set of one or more numbers following the previous expression.

`^` says: "begins with"
`$` says: "ends with"

You should take a look at a tutorial on [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).